# Bash selecting files from directory listing stored in a string

Tags: bash, fastq

I have lets say 50 folders each with a different number of pairs of files that are the input for a command line tool.

```
#for f in ./*shuf; do #lists all the directories
    #FILES=${f}/*.fastq #to get all the fastq files in the directory

    FILES="./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_f.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121103_1_f.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121103_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121214_1_f.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121214_1_r.fastq"
```

What I need to do is divide the files into their respective pairs (one r and one f for each file name), into something that looks like this (for a single pair):

```
echo $PAIR

./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_f.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_r.fastq
```

I will use this as an input which needs to be in this format

```
 (`basename ${PAIR%_*}; $PAIR`):
 C115_7.121017_1 ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_f.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_r.fastq
```

And then loop through all the pairs.

I was attempting to do this with:

```
IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$FILES"
echo "${ADDR[ ]}"
```

but I'm stuck getting an error `${ADDR[ ]}: bad substitution`. Could you please include an explanation of the method as I really want to learn.

EDIT:

To clarify a bit:

this is somewhat what I am looking for the output to be:

```
 IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$FILES"
 pairs="${ADDR[@]}"
 for afile in ${pairs}; do bfile=${afile%_*}; echo ${bfile}_r.fastq ${bfile}_f.fastq; done
```

But without the duplicating:

```
./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_f.fastq
./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121017_1_f.fastq
./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121103_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121103_1_f.fastq
./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121103_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121103_1_f.fastq
./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121214_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121214_1_f.fastq
./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121214_1_r.fastq ./74.C115_7.merge.align.rg.sorted.rmdup.shuf/C115_7.121214_1_f.fastq
```

Comment: `echo "${ADDR[ ]}"` will result in an error.  Not sure what you want, but you might be looking for `echo "${ADDR[@]}"`

Comment: I was wondering what the `@` did, since the example I was looking at was dealing with email addresses I just assumed it must be something to do with that. Still how would you divide the file names into pairs?

Comment: Oh no, `@` denotes a _special parameter_.  I would suggest you to refer to the manual and read about arrays.

Comment: Ah that explains a lot

Comment: You can't reliably store a list of filenames in a string, because filenames can contain any character except the NUL character, and bash uses C strings, which can't contain NULs. You need to use an array.

Comment: By the way -- all-uppercase variable names are reserved for environment variables and shell built-ins; using lowercase names for other variables is strongly preferred, since it means you won't conflict with environment variables by accident.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you talk about pairs, which is why my answer doesn't address it at all.

Comment: With pairs I meant files with the same base name: `C115_7.121017_1` has two files `C115_7.121017_1_r` and `C115_7.121017_1_f`

Comment: ...but the "pairs" you appear to be writing in your sample code are a basename and a fullname; how do filenames that have different final characters relate to the rest of the question? If you could rewrite the question to be clearer about exactly what the output should look like, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob

KEYS=()
declare -A MAP=()

for D in ./*shuf; do
    for F in "$D"/*.fastq; do
        KEY=${F##*/} KEY=${KEY%_*}
        [[ -z ${MAP[$KEY]} ]] && KEYS+=("$KEY")
        MAP[$KEY]+=" $F"
    done
    for KEY in "${KEYS[@]}"; do
        echo "${KEY}${MAP[$KEY]}"
    done
    KEYS=()
    MAP=()
done
```

Or

```
shopt -s nullglob

KEYS=()
declare -A MAP=()

for D in ./*shuf; do
    for F in "$D"/*.fastq; do
        KEY=${F##*/} KEY=${KEY%_*}
        [[ -z ${MAP[$KEY]} ]] && KEYS+=("$KEY")
        MAP[$KEY]+=" $F"
    done
done

for KEY in "${KEYS[@]}"; do
    echo "${KEY}${MAP[$KEY]}"
done
```

You need Bash 4.0 or newer for it. Good luck.

Comment: Could you please put a few comments as to what each line does? Thanks

Comment: @crysis405 Please refer to the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). Everything's in there. `help` and `help <builtin_name>` is also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *shuf; do
  files=( "$f"/*.fastq ) # an array of files, NOT a string
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do # expands each element into a separate parameter
    # write output; note that this is DANGEROUS because it's newline-terminating
    # ...filenames which can potentially themselves contain newlines.
    printf '%s %s\n' "$(basename "${file%_*}")" "$file"
  done
done
```